# Windows 8 network usage stuck at 0 Mbps for all processes

Tags: wireless-networking, windows-8, task-manager

Network utilization of all my processes seems to be frozen at 0 Mbps. See the screenshot below (Task Manager, Processes tab):

[image: Processes]

However, the Performance tab shows that I'm using my network as much as is possible:

[image: Performance]

The same happens when I switch to percentage. What's the problem and how can I fix it?

Comment: Just last night I noticed this too! It has worked before. I thought maybe a recent change to my system would have done it, I'd installed Client Hyper V and SeriousBit Net Balancer the day before.

Comment: Try viewing Network Utilization column in descending order to see processes using more bandwidth. Also check user tab, if there are any other users using network.

Answer (score 1):

Click on"Abrir Monitor de Recursos" (Resource Monitor) [and look here in the network tab](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/datacenter/use-resource-monitor-to-monitor-network-performance/4709) if you can see which tool causes the network IO:

[image]

Comment: This doesn't fix the problem, though it could help get networking data